# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-4.0.so.1: version `LLVM_4.0' not found

Tags: docker, clang, llvm-clang, llvm-4.0, llvm-config

I am trying to run a tool that uses Clang and LLVM. The tool name is cppgrep that is available with the docker. Please find it from the github repository - https://github.com/peter-can-talk/cppnow-2017. I have tried using Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10, I got the same error as below:

```
root@522051d201d2:/home# ./cppgrep -help
./cppgrep: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-4.0.so.1: version `LLVM_4.0' not found (required by ./cppgrep)
./cppgrep: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-4.0.so.1: version `LLVM_4.0' not found (required by ./cppgrep)
root@522051d201d2:/home#
```

After some online search, I found that I had to setup the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. So as a first step I found the library files location in the docker, please find the output below:

```
root@522051d201d2:/home# find / -iname *libclang*.so*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-4.0.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-4.0.so.1
/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/libclang.so.1
/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/libclang-4.0.so
/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/libclang-4.0.0.so
/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/libclang.so
/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/libclang-4.0.so.1
/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.dyndd-x86_64.so
/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-i686.so
/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so
/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-i386.so
```

After this step, I setup the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as follows:

```
root@522051d201d2:/home# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib:/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

And lastly, I have exported it using the command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Now, if I try to run the cppgrep tool, I am still getting the same error. The command to test the tool after building the docker is as follows:
(1) `cd` into the cppgrep directory, like `code/cppgrep`, 
(2) enter the docker container and mount the folder under `/home`:
`$ docker run -it -v $PWD:/home clang` 
(3) run cppgrep using `./cppgrep 'x' test.cpp` command.
It is suppossed to return functions and variables that has name x.

To replicate the error, after downloading and unzipping the file from github repository, build the docker container using `$ docker build -t clang .` command. Then follow 1,2,3 steps in the above paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of days struggle, solved it!!

My initial assumption about the reason for the error is correct. The clang-llvm environment was not available to the cppgrep tool, but I made the mistake in the way of providing the environment information to the cppgrep tool.

The answer has two steps: (1) change the Makefile to point the correct location where you have installed the llvm, in my case, I change the following line in Makefile from `HEADERS := -isystem /llvm/include/` to `HEADERS := -isystem /usr/lib/llvm-4.0/include/`. (2) You have to compile the file again by using the `make` command, just enter an empty space and save the cppgrep.cpp file before giving the command, otherwise, you will get a message as `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`.

That is it, now you should be able to run the cppgrep tool by running `./cppgrep 'x' test.cpp` or `./cppgrep -help`. For using the other tools in this docker such as ast-dump, mccabe, etc. you have to follow the same above two steps before using them.